# When migrating question, provide opportunity to re-tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, migrated-questions

On the Android Enthusiasts SE we get a fair number of Android development questions which are, invariably, migrated to Stack Overflow.

However, the tags that might have been appropriate at AE are not the same as for SO. Let me offer a concrete example: I just migrated a question tagged "2.3-gingerbread" and "development". On AE those tags make sense, as that's the OS being discussed and the topic. However, on SO the question should be tagged "android" and, perhaps, "touch-screen".

Now, I could change the tags on AE, migrate, then change them back. Trouble is "android" is on the tag blacklist for AE. Or, I could edit the tags on the new question on SO, but then I'm not a mod on SO. Either way it's a fair bit of trouble to migrate a question and make it as useful as possible on the destination site.

So, it would be nice if the migration tool offered a way to modify tags as part of the process of moving the question.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I've always just flagged anything I migrate to let the receiving moderators know that something should get retagged, but this would save them the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bad idea, but I think the theory is mods and 10k users watch for incoming questions (which is why there's a [tools list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-imported) for them) and tag them as it happens. You might be familiar enough with SO's tags to do the retagging, but mods and closers throughout the network can't really be expected to know all the tags on all the sites; it should be the responsibility of the site receiving the question to retag it to their liking

Comment: As if I'd go and visit `/tools/*`… All the 10k tools require going to a specific page on each site (except edit approval which has a per-site notification). They aren't useful for reacting to an event. [Now if there was some kind of notification mechanism…](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87397/please-provide-a-configurable-notification-for-tools)

Comment: @Gilles Notifications would be good, but the first thing I used to do when going to SO was open the first seven links on the tools page