# Please provide a configurable notification for tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, moderator-abilities, global-inbox, feed

I would like to have a notification system for action requests — basically things that appear in the 10k tools (spread around multiple pages on each site):

- flags (yes, in addition to the number in yellow, because I have to load a page on that site to get the number; and for 10k you need to go and visit `/tools/flagged`)
- migrated posts (`/tools/posts/migrated/here`)
- suggested edits (yes, in addition to the number in orange, because I have to load a page on that site to get the number)
- possibly close and delete votes (`/review/close`, `/tools?tab=delete`)

The global inbox looks like the logical place to put this. However, I don't want a notification for *everything*. All mod flags, sure (but SO mods might not agree), but not, say, all close votes on SU. So there needs to be some kind of configuration interface, perhaps like the tag sets on https://stackexchange.com/. Maybe something like an RSS feed that I'd filter at my end would be easier on the UI (though if you're 10k on SO, that's already a lot of traffic).

<sub>The 2.0 API could in principle allow authenticated feeds. I will take “here's the API, write your own code” as an answer where applicable. But as far as I can tell, only [suggested edits](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits) are available through the API, not migrations, close votes, delete votes, migrated posts or flags. Furthermore the API only allows polling at a reasonably slow rate; I want notifications to come quickly (a 1 minute propagation delay would be acceptable, but not a hourly feed).</sub>

Comment: It'd be a royal PitA to implement, but I do think authenticated feeds are the way to go.

Comment: Related: [One SE site to rule them all (show flags and more on stackexchange.com)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122081)